# Python - How to sum values in file

Tags: python, list, file

So i have a file. Where there is 3 lines and each line tells Name;sport:points

```
Kevin;Football:604,196,47;Golf:349,0,0;Tennis:797,426,124
Julia;Football:350,254,1;Golf:242,58,38
Bob;Football:260,18,0
```

i have a code, but i don't know how to sum points in each sport

```
f=open("points.txt", "r")
s=f.readlines()
p=str(s)

for line in s:
    printnum=0
    printnum+=float(line)



    for line in s:
        if p.isdigit():
            total=0
            for number in s:
                total+=int(number)
                print(total)
```

So the result should look like

```
Alvin:
- Football: 278
Kevin:
- Football: 847
- Golf: 349
- Tennis: 1347
Sam:
- Football: 605
- Golf: 338
```

So basically i don't know hot to sum keys values

Comment: Please make the input and desired output match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from ast import literal_eval as leval

my_dict = {}
for line in s:
    name, *sports = line.split(';')
    my_dict[name] = {sport.split(':')[0]: sum(leval(sport.split(':')[1])) for sport in sports}

for player in my_dict:
    print('{}:'.format(player))
    for sport in my_dict[player]:
        print(' - {}: {}'.format(sport, my_dict[player][sport]))

# Produces:
# Kevin:
#  - Golf: 349
#  - Tennis: 1347
#  - Football: 847
# Julia:
#  - Golf: 338
#  - Football: 605
# Bob:
#  - Football: 278
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into using the CSV module:

```
import csv

points = {}

with open('points.txt', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        points[row[0]] = {}
        for sport in row[1:]:
            name = sport[:sport.find(':')] # get the name of the sport
            scores = sport[sport.find(':')+1:].split(',')
            total_score = 0
            for score in scores:
                total_score = int(score) # add all the scores together
            points[row[0]][name] = total_score
print(points)

# Print the resuslts in the order that you want
for name, sports in sorted(points.items()):
    print(name + ':')
    for sport_name, points in sorted(sports.items()):
        print('-', sport_name + ':', + points)
```

This gives us:

```
Bob:
- Football: 0
Julia:
- Football: 1
- Golf: 38
Kevin:
- Football: 47
- Golf: 0
- Tennis: 124
```

[try online](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python3_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMRTBKU1pQRVBUcDQ)

Answer (score 0):

This will generate list of dictonaries describing players.

```
player_list = []

with open("dane") as f_obj:
    for line in f_obj.readlines():
        player_line = line.split(';')
        player_data = {'name': player_line[0]}

        for elem in player_line[1:]:
            sport = elem.split(':')
            sport_name = sport[0]
            points = sport[1].split(',')
            sum_points = 0
            for p in points:
                sum_points += int(p)

            player_data[sport_name] = sum_points

        player_list.append(player_data)

print(player_list)
```

Now you just need to format printing of this list like you want.

This is how this list looks like:

```
[{'name': 'Kevin', 'Golf': 349, 'Football': 847, 'Tennis': 1347}, {'name': 'Julia', 'Golf': 338, 'Football': 605}, {'name': 'Bob', 'Football': 278}]
```